# error 550 when IMAP users send mail to outside

Tags: exchange, exchange-2019

in the newly installed exchange 2019 I'm facing a problem, employees that send mails to outside with IMAP are getting this error in their inbox:

Server error: '550 5.7.54 SMTP; Unable to relay recipient in non-accepted domain'

the receive connector is the default connector and the domain that users are created is different than the email domain, here is the log I found
[the log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lvfcQ.png)

the xxxx.com is the real email address and YYYY.com is the local domain name

Answer (score 0):

By default Exchange server won't let you relay emails to outside recipients.

You may need to follow these steps to create a dedicated receive connector used for relay:

**1.create a new receive connector**

It is not recommended by Microsoft to modify the default ones as it often causes issues.

**2.configure the permissions on the receive connector**

**3.specify allowed ip addresses to allow anonymous relay only from these ip addresses.**

If not, your server would become an open relay.

The detailed steps are introduced in this Microsoft documentation:

[Allow anonymous relay on Exchange servers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/mail-flow/connectors/allow-anonymous-relay?view=exchserver-2019)